# C++ template dependencies

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question about circular dependencies with templates in c++.
I have two template classes, Rotation3 and Vector3.
The rotation holds a horizontal and vertical rotation, while the vector has x y and z components.

I would like each class to have a constructor for the other:

```
Vector3<T>::Vector3(const Rotation3<T>& rot)
```

and...

```
Vector3<T>::Rotation3(const Vector3<T>& vec)
```

but, because templates can't be put in the .cpp file, and must be in the .h, that means that both the Vector3.h and Rotation3.h would have to include each other in order to use each other for their constructors. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help in advance, I'm rather new to c++, and I would really like to know how someone with experience would go about designing this.

Comment: I wonder how on earth it's possible to convert between both.

Comment: Why don't you just put them in the same file

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I figured out the math, thats not the issue. You have to use rotation matrices and other things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little weird by using `#include` directives that are not near the beginning of the file, but effective.  The include guards are even more important than usual.

```
// Vector3.hpp
#ifndef VECTOR3_HPP_
#define VECTOR3_HPP_

template<typename T> class Rotation3;

template<typename T> class Vector3
{
public:
    explicit Vector3(const Rotation3<T>&);
};

#include "Rotation3.hpp"

template<typename T>
Vector3<T>::Vector3(const Rotation3<T>& r)
{ /*...*/ }

#endif

// Rotation3.hpp
#ifndef ROTATION3_HPP_
#define ROTATION3_HPP_

template<typename T> class Vector3;

template<typename T> class Rotation3
{
public:
    explicit Rotation3(const Vector3<T>&);
};

#include "Vector.hpp"

template<typename T>
Rotation3<T>::Rotation3(const Vector3<T>& v)
{ /*...*/ }

#endif
```

Comment: thanks, I see how that works. It is a little weird, but it's the only way I can see. Thanks, accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If both Vector3 and Rotatio3 are Templates then nothing will happen because a template does not generate an object until is specialized or used (for example vector3).

You could create another class that includes both vector3 and Rotation3 either by composition or inheritance and use them as you want. This could also be a template (template Vector3, template Rotation3> Example)

Answer (score 0):

As usual you can just declare stuff, and that declaration may be well enough for purposes. Declaration of the template is similar to all others, just leave out the definition part.

Also template class member function can be defined outside the class. You can split your header to just defining the class and another implementing the functions. Then you can include them interleaved.